# Algolia searchbox - QueryHook prop is not working

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have a website build with React that uses Algolia to index images that users can search through.

I want to create suggestions under the search bar much like the image below:
[image]

so that a user can click on it and that's the search input or they can type. I'm using a  widget and a queryHook property

I'm trying to use the query hook with the following code:

```
const queryHook = (query, search) => {
  search(query);
};

function Search() {
  return <SearchBox queryHook={queryHook} />;
}
```

I got this code from [Aloglia docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/react/?client=JavaScript)

But i get the error:

> search is not a function
> TypeError: search is not a function

This is confusing because search is not defined in the docs as well.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. Instead of using the queryHook, I created my own custom searchBox, this gave me the freedom to enter queries in different ways than just typing into search. Most of this code can be found in this algolia [doc](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/react/?client=JavaScript#hook-example).

There is a `<keywords />` component that has all the keywords that i want to show below the search bar. The words are mapped through and when a user clicks on it, the `clickWord` function will turn it into a search query.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useInstantSearch, useSearchBox } from "react-instantsearch";
import Keywords from "./Keywords";

export default function CustomSearchBox(props) {
  const { query, refine } = useSearchBox(props);
  const { status } = useInstantSearch();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(query);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const isSearchStalled = status === "stalled";

  function setQuery(newQuery) {
    setInputValue(newQuery);

    refine(newQuery);
  }

  const clickWord = (word) => {
    setQuery(word);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-11/12 md:w-1/2 items-center mx-auto mb-5 pt-3">
        <form
          action=""
          role="search"
          noValidate
          className="relative h-1/2"
          onSubmit={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            if (inputRef.current) {
              inputRef.current.blur();
            }
          }}
          onReset={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            setQuery("");

            if (inputRef.current) {
              inputRef.current.focus();
            }
          }}
        >
          <input
            className="caret-orange-500 block w-full md:pl-9 md:pr-3 py-2 border-orange-400 ring-orange-400 placeholder-slate-400 focus:border-1 focus:outline-none focus:border-orange-400 focus:ring-orange-400 rounded-md focus:ring-1"
            ref={inputRef}
            autoComplete="off"
            autoCorrect="off"
            autoCapitalize="off"
            placeholder="enter search query"
            spellCheck={false}
            maxLength={512}
            type="search"
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={(event) => {
              setQuery(event.currentTarget.value);
            }}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <button
            type="reset"
            hidden={inputValue.length === 0 || isSearchStalled}
          >
            Reset
          </button>
          <span hidden={!isSearchStalled}>Searching…</span>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Keywords clickWord={clickWord} />
    </>
  );
}
```